# How can I upload a XML file to a shared folder with Jmeter?

Tags: upload, jmeter

I want to upload a xml file to a shared folder.
for example the file must go to:
\\xxx.xxx.intra\xxxx\xxx\out

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMeter SSH SFTP sampler.
You can refer to below links which will give you insights on how to install
JMeter SSH SFTP sampler
https://github.com/linkeshkanna/Jmeter.SSH.FTP.Request
https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler

This sampler sets up SFTP client via JMeter. 
Make sure you have SSH server running on the place where you want to upload your file.

Comment: The problem is that I don't  have the rights to download and install things on the computer.  So is there any other things that I can do??

Comment: If you are using Linux env then SSH demon is embedded into it hence you would not require to install SSH server. If you can't download 2 jars for SSH SFTP sampler then you can install Jmeter plugin manger and download this sampler

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to download anything but JMeter, it has  [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)

> The OS Process Sampler is a sampler that can be used to execute commands on the local machine.
>   It should allow execution of any command that can be run from the command line.

You can use to execute command also on shared folder,
just add it as a parameter to you command.

If it's windows it may not work, so you can map you shared folder to a drive and then execute your command on the drive (as `P:`)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), the relevant code would be something like:

```
def source = new File('c:\\apps\\jmeter\\bin\\log4j2.xml') // replace it with your own path
def destination = new File('\\\\\xxx.xxx.intra\\xxxx\\xxx\\out\\' + source.getName())
destination << source
```

References:

- [Groovy Copy File Examples](http://grails.asia/groovy-copy-file-examples)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)